# Stock market API - News on stock price movement

Tags: api, data, news, stock

I'm currently on the lookout for an API that can provide me with daily stock market news specifically focused on the reasons behind a stock's price movement on a given day.

To clarify, I'm not interested in general news about the stock or broad market updates (which most APIs cover), but rather detailed information about the catalysts influencing a stock's movement. Whether it's earnings reports, significant announcements, or other factors – that's what I'm after.

If any of you are aware of such APIs or have recommendations, I would greatly appreciate your insights.